# How can I use SVN in BBedit?

Tags: macos, editor, bbedit

I want to use the SVN synchronization in BBedit (version 10.0) for project developed in Lua language. Should I download a SVN plugin (if yes, from where?) or BBEedit has it (if yes, in which menu is it?)
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has Subversion support:

From http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/benefitsintegrate.html#SourceManagement

> Direct integration with Subversion: **BBEdit’s Subversion menu** includes all of the commands that you need for common operations. In addition, when committing from within BBEdit, a handy submission form makes it easy to write commit comments.

[image]

Note also, from http://pine.barebones.com/manual/BBEdit_10_User_Manual.pdf

> In order to enable BBEdit’s Subversion integration, you must have Subversion 1.1 or later 
>   installed and available in the PATH for GUI applications (as controlled by ~/.MacOSX/
>   environment.plist). You must also have a Subversion working copy which has been 
>   checked out via the command line.

Comment: I need to install subversion in order to see SVN dialog box? (For now I have only BBedit installed).Thanks

Comment: You likely already have the svn client; what you need is a svn working. Check out a small open source project (say, `svn checkout http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/spamassassin/trunk/build/mkupdates test`), open one of the files in there, and see if it becomes enabled.

Comment: I don't understand what I should open and how. I go to link http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/spamassassin/trunk/build/mkupdates" and there are some files. I copied one of them as a "new file" to BBedit. I guess I miss something. Can you please explain me some more what exactly I should open and where in order to check if I have a SVN client? Thanks.

Comment: Open terminal. Type: `svn checkout http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/spamassassin/trunk/build/mkupdates test` at the prompt. You'll get a directory called `test` with some files in it. Visit one of those files with BBEdit.

Comment: I typed it in the terminal. I get answer there "Checked out revision 1337816". What should I do now?

Comment: As I said: open BBEdit, and try to open one of the files in that new `test` directory, say `run_nightly`.

Comment: I succeeded to open "run_nightly" file in BBEdit. What should I see or do now? Thanks